# JS - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I need to pass an id (that is a UUID) to a function to make a get request but when I click on "Descargar" I get the message

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at mis_solicitudes.html:1:19)

I understand the html is not reading de uuid I'm passing as an entry parameter for the function descarga.

Can you please help me?

Here is my complete JS code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    listarTkt();
  };
  
  
  
  function listarTkt() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", token);
  
  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers,
  redirect: 'follow'
  };
  
  fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
    if (result.length === 0) {
      document.getElementById("tableBody").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("tableBody").innerHTML = "<h1>No hay solicitudes</h1>";
    } else {
        let dataArray = result;
        for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
             let id = dataArray[i].request_id.toString();
             console.log(typeof(id));
          tr = $('<tr/>');
          tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].tkt_date + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].tkt_checkout_nr + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].tkt_store_nr + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + dataArray[i].tkt_op_nr + "</td>");
          if (dataArray[i].status === 5){
            tr.append("<td>No encontrado(5)</td>");
          } else if (dataArray[i].status === 0) {
            tr.append("<td>Solicitud nueva</td>");
          } else if (dataArray[i].status === 1) {
            tr.append("<td>Solicitud en proceso</td>");
          } else if (dataArray[i].status === 3) {
            tr.append("<td>Lista para descargar</td>");
          } else if (dataArray[i].status === 6) {
            tr.append("<td>No encontrado(6)</td>");
          } else if (dataArray[i].status === 9) {
            tr.append("<td>Error</td>");
          }
          if (dataArray[i].status === 3) {
            console.log(id);
            tr.append("<td>" + "<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick='descarga(" + id + ")'>Descargar</button>" + "</td>");
           
  
          } else {
            tr.append("<td></td>");
          }
  
          
          $('#tableBody').append(tr);
        
        
          }
        
        
        
      }
    })
  
  
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
  
  function descarga(id) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", token);
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  
    let requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        redirect: 'follow'
    }
  
    fetch(downloadUrl +  id + "/content", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
        const blob = new Blob([result], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "ticket.pdf";
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```

Comment: Where/when do you see that error? **Exactly** what does the error message say, including line number etc?

Comment: Also there's a good chance that the error is coming from the code involved with the `fetch()`, specifically where you expect JSON but get HTML, however that code was not posted so it's very hard to say.

Comment: There’s an error inside code you’re not showing?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The error is exactly what I posted on the line of the function descarga()

Comment: It does not make the request yet because it does not accept the id due to sintaxis. So I do not consider neccesary to include the fetch()

Comment: the id is a guid

Comment: So the syntax error is where you call the function? Or in code loaded before it? You don’t show that either.—it’s not clear how anybody could help.

Comment: The error message should have a line number. And if you click on it, the browser will take you to that line of the code and you'll see a squiggle under the invalid syntax. Which line is it?

Comment: Is result defined anywhere? You use it on the first line. If that’s the first reference to it, then there’s your problem.

Comment: I edit my question hoping it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that I need to escape stating and closing quotes of onclick=""

```
tr.append("<td>" + "<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick=\"descarga('" + id + "')\"><i class='bi bi-eye'></i></button>" + "</td>");
```